# widget auto-create feature not showing on android studio

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, widget, action

I want to automatically create a widget in android studio for my react native app. The android studio documentation shows that this can be done by going to new>widget>app widget. But my widget function is not displayed. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance for your reply.[This is what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxL5K.png)

[This is what is in the documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxh47.png)

Answer (score 2):

Xml-> design-> Left -> Palette
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SY7HT.png

Comment: thanks for the response but i need to create a widget for android as shown here. Note: Android Studio automatically creates a set of AppWidgetProviderInfoAppWidgetProvider, , and view layout files. Simply choose New > Widget > App Widget.  But I don't have widget options when I create a new file

Comment: You are welcome, which version of Android are you using?

Comment: bumblebee // 2021.1.1

Comment: I will be very grateful if you explain in more detail. I am new to android development

Comment: I can't figure it out without seeing it, but it may be caused by a poorly installed SDK.
Tools->SDK Manager